# hammer.js with several different divs

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, hammer.js

```
onPan = (ev) ->
  console.log(ev)

createHammer = (v) ->
  mc = new Hammer.Manager(v, {})
  mc.add new Hammer.Pan(
    direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL
    threshold: 20
  )
  mc.on 'panleft panright', onPan

createHammer for v in document.querySelectorAll('.market-place .vehicle')
```

I have a bunch of `<li>`s that I want to be able to swipe left and right with an action for each (like tinder, among other things). This is my attempt to get them all. I was able to get the first element to spit out info in the console, but not with this loop. Ideas?

I tried with jquery selectors, but accomplished even less =/

Comment: Don't you mean `createHammer(v) for v ....`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered wrapping the call to `createHammer(v)` to ensure every `v` is "secured" in a Closure? In Coffeescript you can easily do this with the `do` keyword. Read more about it [here](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) (last paragraph of this section):

```
for v in document.querySelectorAll('.market-place .vehicle')
  do(v) ->
    createHammer(v)
```